# Pointcut with a class name pattern

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

test.core and I want an aspect around every class in that or a sub-package with the name pattern *Service*.

sth like this: "execution(public de.test.core..*Service*.*(..)" but it doesn t seem to work.

Is aspectJ even able to match to a class pattern?

Answer (score 5):

Match all methods defined in beans whose name ends with ‘Service’.

```
bean(*Service)
```

Match by Service pattern

```
@Pointcut("within(*..*Service)")
public void inServiceClass() {}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your post but this is a pattern based on the bean name, I need it based on the class name

Comment: How is your packages structured, do you Have other pattern then *Service in service package?

Comment: Hi, no I don't have them in a .service. package so I want to filter them by class name e.g. MySuperServiceImpl

Comment: Try this @Pointcut("within(*..*Service)")

Comment: Thanks, your answer was still really helpful because it showed me how to match only part of a class/method name