# Spring AoP Reference all methods from all classes in any package ending in a certain String in a pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I want to reference all public methods from all classes in any package ending in a certain String in a pointcut.

I have tried:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *.*SomeString.*(..))")
```

Edit: Since the classes I want to reference are all coming from the Application Context, I know I can do this using bean()

```
@Pointcut("bean(*SomeString)")
```

but I would prefer to use execution().

Comment: See doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html, section 6.2.3.4. In your case it it @Pointcut("execution(public * *SomeString(..))")

Comment: I think the OP was talking about **classes** ending with a certain substring. What @kidnan1991 gave him was **methods** ending with that substring. So please can the OP clarify which of the two he/she wants? Then I can answer.

Comment: @kriegaex I am talking about all public method of all classes ending with a certain substring.

Comment: Duplicate -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756411/pointcut-with-a-class-name-pattern my first duplicate was a copy paste error!

Comment: @feelingunwelcome I'm trying to select all **public** methods of all classes (in any package) ending with a certain substring. That StackOverflow answer selects **all** methods of all classes ending with a certain substring, which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: @sdlfyeiwyrw, your last comment to me is still ambiguous, let me show it with additional parentheses: _"all public methods of all (**classes** ending with a certain substring)"_ Versus: _"all public **methods** (of all classes) ending with a certain substring"_. I think you mean the first one, like I already said. But just to be sure I covered both in my answer below.

Comment: @sdlfyeiwyrw could you post more of the code? The entire definition of the `@Pointcut`s and where you're using them in a `@Around` or `@Before` or whatever the case may be?

Comment: @GabrielGates I am using the pointcut I defined above in `@Around()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with `*.*SomeString` is that it only looks for **classes** in the first package level, such as `foo.BarSomeString` or `hello.MySomeString`, but not in subpackages such as `foo.aaa.bbb.BarSomeString` or `hello.xxx.MySomeString`.

If the package name is completely irrelevant, you can use wildcards:

```java
execution(public * *..*SomeString.*(..))
```

BTW, if you were using full AspectJ instead of Spring AOP, you could use this shortcut (I have no idea why Spring AOP does not like it because it also uses an AspectJ library for pointcut matching):

```java
execution(public * *SomeString.*(..))
```

If you want to define a base backage and subpackage beneath it, you can use the `..` syntax:

```java
execution(public * de.scrum_master..*SomeString.*(..))
```

An alternative to the latter would be to use `within()` in order to limit the package:

```java
execution(public * *(..)) && within(de.scrum_master..*SomeString)
```

By the way, in AspectJ you really need the `execution()` pointcut because it has many more pointcut types, but in Spring AOP implicitly all pointcuts are execution pointcuts because that is the only joinpoint type supported by Spring AOP due to its proxy-based nature. So you could also just write:

```java
within(de.scrum_master..*SomeString)
```

For interface-based proxies (Java dynamic proxy) this is the same because only public methods are supported. The only slight difference here is that for CGLIB proxies (when proxying classes, not interfaces, or by configuration for all proxies) this would also match protected and package-scoped methods.

---

Slightly off-topic, here is how to do the same not for classes but **methods** with a special suffix:

```java
execution(public * *SomeString(..))
```

If you want to also limit the package/class scope you can just combine it:

```java
execution(public * *SomeString(..)) && within(de.scrum_master..*)
```

Or equivalently:

```java
execution(public * de.scrum_master..*SomeString(..))
```

So if you want to limit package, class and mathod name all at once you do this:

```java
execution(public * de.scrum_master..*Controller.*SomeString(..))
```

Or equivalently:

```java
execution(public * *SomeString(..)) && within(de.scrum_master..*Controller)
```

Comment: Thank you guy, you taught me alot about AOP \m/

Comment: Thanks for responding, but `execution(public * *SomeString.*(..))` is not working for me.

Comment: My bad, I only tested in AspectJ. Spring AOP does not seem to like that shortcut syntax from AspectJ. I updated the answer showing a workaround. I expect all the other examples to work in both Spring AOP and AJ.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `execution` and `within` pointcuts to meet your needs.

You can use `within` to select all methods of classes ending in a certain substring like this:

```
within(*..*SomeString)
```

You can use `execution` to select all public methods like this:

```
execution(public * *(..))
```

Combined, they will select all public methods of **all classes ending with a certain substring**.

```
within(*..*SomeString) && execution(public * *(..))
```

Comment: What is new about this answer? Mine also shows combinations of `execution()` and `within()`, both for classes and methods ending with a certain string plus combinations of both. With all due respect, but this looks as if you saw the bounty and wanted to snatch it from someone who had already answered before there even was a bounty.

Comment: @kriegaex At the time of my answer, sdlfyeiwyrw had said that your answer was not working for him/her.

Comment: I see. Maybe a comment under mine would have sufficed because my answer is basically a superset of yours. No offense meant.

Comment: To @sdlfyeiwyrw: I did all the work one day before this guy, my answer is also correct as you even admit in your comment (and already was when you were commenting on this answer), explains why your original code was not working, explains other cases and even differences between AspectJ and Spring AOP, and you accept this answer with a reward of 300 points? Thank you so much for making it really worth while helping you. I think you were just being really unfair here. Call me a sore loser if you like, but this is my opinion.